# CodeIgniter image crop only on dynamic output

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-resizing

I'm trying to crop an image in CodeIgniter, using the built in image manipulation class. The code below works fine, you get a resized image output to the browser. However, when you remove the "`$config['dynamic_output'] = TRUE;`" line it no longer crops the image, and just saves the original image instead. What am I doing wrong?!

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

```
public function crop() {        
    $config['library_path'] = '/usr/local/bin';
    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/static/images/moose_resized.jpg';
    $config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/static/images/moose_thumb.jpg';
    $config['x_axis'] = '0';
    $config['y_axis'] = '74';
    $config['width'] = '222';
    $config['height'] = '111';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['quality'] = '100';
    $config['dynamic_output'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    $this->image_lib->crop();

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    $this->load->view('crop');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so nobody get any points because they didn't spot the stupid mistake in the code above!

```
$this->image_lib->crop();

if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

In a moment of temporary insanity I added in the crop line, rather than replacing the resize one in the if statement. Duh!